# How do I unwrap Task<IEnumerable> to work with the results?

Tags: c#, async-await

I am setting up a `Task[]` array so I can use `Task.WhenAll()` like this:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[2];

        tasks[0] = _widgetDataService.RetrieveAsync<CollaboratorNetworkNode>(
            "get_collaborator_nodes", portfolio,
            recentFys, nodesSwitch);

        tasks[1]  = _widgetDataService.RetrieveAsync<CollaboratorNetworkEdge>(
            "get_collaborator_edges", portfolio, recentFys);

        await Task.WhenAll();
```

The code runs fine and gets to a break point at `Task.WhenAll`.

But now I go to run this code:

```
var nodes = from pi in (IEnumerable<CollaboratorNetworkNode>)tasks[0]
                    select new GraphNode { Id = pi.ProfileId, Properties = pi, Labels = new[] { "Person" } };
```

and I get the error message:

> Unable to cast object of type 
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[Nete.Ireport.Models.ViewModels.CollaboratorNetworkNode]]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[Nete.Ireport.Models.ViewModels.CollaboratorNetworkNode]'.

If I try to just run this:

```
var nodes = from pi in tasks[0]
                    select new GraphNode { Id = pi.ProfileId, Properties = pi, Labels = new[] { "Person" } };
```

I cannot compile because I get the red squiggly with:

> Task does not contain a definition for Select and the best extension
>   method overload "DynamicQueryable.Select(IQueryable, string, params
>   object[] requires a receiver of type IQueryable.

We are just trying to run these two Retrieve Services each of which are 10 seconds.  So our call is 20 seconds.
I am getting to the break point now in 13 to 15 seconds.
So if I can get this to work I have shaved off 5 to 7 seconds.

But I don't know how to use the results.

How can I finish up this method?

Comment: You need to use Task.Result. If you're treating your task as a plain `Task` (as opposed to a `Task<T>`), then you'll need to cast it first to gain access to `.Result.`

Comment: `await Task.WhenAll();` this isn't going to do anything....

Comment: Glorin - Can you give a little more detail then that?

Comment: It takes a arguments, a.k.a a list of Tasks that it should wait for...

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the array of tasks to the `WhenAll` method:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Then you can store the results using the `Result` Property:

```
var result1 = (Task[0] as Task<IEnumerable<CollaboratorNetworkNode>>).Result;
var result2 = (Task[1] as Task<IEnumerable<CollaboratorNetworkEdge>>).Result;
```

Change the above to whatever is the return type of the methods you're calling asynchronously.

**Note:** Use `Task.Result` very carefully if the `Task` is not yet completed.

Answer (score 0):

your function `_widgetDataService.RetrieveAsync<CollaboratorNetworkEdge>` has a return value, probably of type `Task<IEnumerable<CollaboratorNetworkNode>>`

You should not put these return values in an array of `Task`, but in an array of `Task<IEnumerable<CollaboratorNetworkNode>>`

```
var tasks = new Task<IEnumerable<CollaboratorNetWorkNode>>[][2];
tasks[0] = _widgetDataService.RetrieveAsync<CollaboratorNetworkNode>(
        "get_collaborator_nodes", portfolio,
        recentFys, nodesSwitch);

tasks[1]  = _widgetDataService.RetrieveAsync<CollaboratorNetworkEdge>(
        "get_collaborator_edges", portfolio, recentFys);
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var nodes = tasks[0].Result.Select(pi=> new GraphNode
{
    Id = pi.ProfileId,
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your array declaration that's causing the problem. As Harald suggested, it should use the appropriate `Task<T>` type, rather than discarding the type information by using `Task`:

```
var tasks = new Task<IEnumerable<CollaboratorNetworkNode>>[2];
tasks[0] = _widgetDataService.RetrieveAsync<CollaboratorNetworkNode>(
        "get_collaborator_nodes", portfolio,
        recentFys, nodesSwitch);
tasks[1]  = _widgetDataService.RetrieveAsync<CollaboratorNetworkEdge>(
        "get_collaborator_edges", portfolio, recentFys);
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
// results[0] is IEnumerable<CollaboratorNetworkNode>
// results[1] is IEnumerable<CollaboratorNetworkNode>

var nodes = from pi in results[0]
            select new GraphNode { Id = pi.ProfileId, Properties = pi, Labels = new[] { "Person" } };
```

I recommend using the result of `await Task.WhenAll` when possible (as this code does). If not possible (i.e., if the tasks are different types), then you should use `await` to retrieve the results, *not* `Result`. `Result` will wrap any exceptions in `AggregateException`, which complicates error handling.